# Active Directory password policy enforcement when creating accounts through C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC website using C# which will allow a user to create an AD account through a front end web page. The idea being you enter the relevant details on the front end, hit submit and I then create the AD account behind the scenes through C# using the details you've entered.

Now, if the AD server has specific password policies (i.e. length, complexity etc) is there anyway to have the front end use those policies directly rather than attempting to recreate them through regex etc?

The reason is that if the AD policy is later changed then if they're not linked the front end is then out of sync and also needs to be changed.

I'm not that familiar with AD but perhaps there is some password policy entity or similar that I can use to check password details (even server side would be fine).

Does such a thing exist or if not how do people recommend getting around the out-of-sync issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is just don't implement the policies in your front end at all.

AD will let you know if what the user entered does not comply with the password policy by means of error codes which you can handle and present to the user in a helpful way.

You don't want to duplicate processes. The process of verifying compliance with password policies is done by the domain controller and should stay there.

Comment: I see your point but in my specific case there's going to be a few other things happening under the hood before the AD account is created. I am anticipating a poor user experience if, after waiting for these other things to complete you only then get told your password needs to be longer. Normally this feedback occurs before you can even submit the form.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton Change the order of processes? After all, if the other processes rely on or are related to the created user, you should do that first anyway as there is loads of other reasons the user might not get created. Maybe the name already exists, maybe the dc isn't available, maybe someone moved your destination OU, maybe the domain is in read only mode or run out of sids.

Comment: Fair enough. At the moment the proposal is that another entity needs to be created first and then the AD account created with details from that previously created entity. Technically we could reverse this though and create the AD account first. Thanks for the suggestion. The upshot of this is that it appears there is no way of querying the AD password policy separately from creating an account. This isn't ideal for me but if it's the only way it's the only way.

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton The only "way" would be to parse the group policy xml files in the sysvol folder but even then you'd need to know how/where theyre applied to work out any overriding settings etc

Comment: And that way sounds messy so it doesn't look like I can do this without relying on AD to provide the feedback. Thanks, I'll mark it as the answer.